# Is there a function to update a filtered dictionary on a change in an input value in Python and Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have a dictionary of house data I am wanting to filter by price.

Here is the current structure in index route:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    output_dict = purchaseDF.to_dict(orient='records')

    for sub in output_dict:
        for key in sub:
            sub['ListPrice'] = float(sub['ListPrice'])

    res = [d for d in output_dict if d['ListPrice']<=float(calcprice())]
```

Here is the calcprice route:

```
@app.route('/calcprice', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def calcprice():
    price = '120000'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        testVal = request.form
        price = str(testVal['Income'])
    return price
```

I have a default value that gets overwritten by the form in Flask when the value changes.

I am stuck on getting the dictionary to update on a change from the form in Flask.

Comment: iterating over a dict just iterates over the keys. you can use `your_dict.items()` to get key/value pairs. can you show a snippet of what `output_dict` looks like? because i'm not even sure how you're not getting an error on this code.

Comment: Yes, sir. 

{'MLSNumber': '4144075', 'ListPrice': '565000.00', 'BedsTotal': '4', 'MLSAreaMinor': 'Cheyenne Run', 'StreetNumber': '859', 'StreetName': 'Redemption', 'PostalCode': '80905', 'TaxAmount': '1366.00'}

Comment: for key in sub:  --> I zapped this line as it was apparently pointless

Comment: Oh I see, I just ran some sample code like what you have: `output_dict` is a *list* of dicts!

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
result_list = []

for item in output_list: 
    item['ListPrice'] = float(item['ListPrice']) 
    if item['ListPrice'] <= float(calcprice()): 
        result_list.append(item)
```

I tested that the above does what you want with this sample data from your comment:

```
In [10]: output_list
Out[10]: 
[{'MLSNumber': '4144075',
  'ListPrice': 565000.0,
  'BedsTotal': '4',
  'MLSAreaMinor': 'Cheyenne Run',
  'StreetNumber': '859',
  'StreetName': 'Redemption',
  'PostalCode': '80905',
  'TaxAmount': '1366.00'}]
```

Comment: Thank you. How do I get the data on the index.html to update on a change in the price? 

Here's the div...but when the price is change, the list isn't updating.

Comment: <div class="row">
        {% for item in purchase %}
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title"> MLS: {{ item['MLSNumber'] }}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">List Price: {{ item['ListPrice'] }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        
    </div>

Comment: Hm, actually, ya this isn't the full problem: how are you even starting off with `purchaseDF`? Where is that data coming from?